# is using an integer to store many bool worth the effort?

Tags: c++, c

I was considering ways to reduce memory footprint, and it is constantly mentioned that a `bool` takes up more memory than it logically needs to, as a byproduct of processor design.
it is also sometimes mentioned that one could store several `bool` within an `int`.
I am wondering if this would actually be more memory efficient?

if we have a usecase where we can use a significant portion of 32 (or 64) `bool`. and we decide to store all of them in a single int. then on the surface we have saved

`7 (bits) * 32 (size of int) = 224 (bits) or 28 (bytes)`

but in order to get each of those bits from the int, we needed to use some method of masking
such as:

- bit shifting the `int` both directions `(int<<x)>>y` here we need to load and store x,y which are probably an int, but you could get them smaller depending on the use case
- masking the `int`: `int & int2` here we also store an additional int, which is stored and loaded

even if these aren't stored as variables, and they are defined statically within the code, it still ends up using additional memory, as it will increase the memory footprint of the instructions. as well as the instructions for the masking steps.

is there any way to do this that isn't actually worse for memory usage than just taking the hit on 7 wasted bits?

Comment: Please choose one language. Don't spam language tags. It is only going to result in down- and/or closure votes.

Comment: `std::bitset` and (unfortunately, alas that ship has sailed) `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: In C you would use bitfields for this. [And it doesn't always lead to more instructions used](https://godbolt.org/z/f7Yqjsxo7). There can be less needed to pass it as an argument, copy or assign to it.

Comment: Saving 28 bytes in total probably isn't worth the increased maintainance in this case. If you save this much memory once for a data structure you use 1000000 times, this may be different. Note that you do not know how exactly the compiler deals with the logic you're using to access the values; optimizations could be happening, different compilers could do different optimizations, ... Probably the only way to determine, if the modification is worth it is to measure...

Comment: Beware that the semantics are different between packed bits (whether using manual masking or bitfields) vs separate array elements.  Separate array elements can safely be accessed simultaneously from separate threads, even if some are writing.  Bit manipulations on the other hand require you to synchronize all users of different bits that may fall in the same integer.

Comment: This question cannot be answered in general since it depends on various unknowns not covered by the C/C++ standards such as the system architecture (CPU type, memory properties, number of booleans to store, how the booleans are used, ...). For example, a given CPU may offer specialized operations for bit manipulation while others may not. Also, "worth the effort" may include such things as code development effort, maintenance effort and readability.

Comment: @BenVoigt `Separate array elements can safely be accessed simultaneously from separate threads` In terms of correctness, yes. But you may still suffer from false sharing resulting in similar overhead to the synchronisation when accessing adjacent array elements from multiple threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are describing a text book example of a trade-off.
Yes, several bools in one int is hugeley more memory efficient - in itself.
Yes, you need to spend code to use that.
Yes, for only a few bools (for different values of "few"), the code might take more space than you save.

However, you could look at the kind of memory which is used. In some environments, RAM (which is saved by your idea) is much more expensive than ROM (which has to be paid for your idea).
Also, the price to pay is mostly paid once for implementation and only paid a fraction for using, especially when the using code is reused, e.g. in loops.

Altogether, in case of many bools, you can save more than you pay.
The point of actually saving needs to be determined for the special case.

On the other hand, you have missed on "currency" on the price-tag for the idea. You not only pay in memory, you also pay in execution time. You focused your question on memory, so I won't elaborate here. But for anything time critical, you should take the longer execution time into conisderation. You might find that saving memory is quite achievable with your idea, but the whole thing gets unbearably slow.
Again from the other side, as Eric Postpischil points out in a comment, execution speed can also improve due to cache effects from better memory footprint.

Comment: There are more currencies, I could name a few, but that would probably trigger opinions which don't really help here.

Comment: Note that execution time may improve with packed bits, as reducing memory footprint can improve cache use.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You convinced me, I did not think of that. Without further research I am convinced that cache effects (especially with smaller memory footprint, as you mention) can increase speed. And I would not even be surprised if that is a widely occurring observation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I know someone who designs and builds network routers for ISPs and he found precisely this.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if this would actually be more memory efficient?

Potentially yes. Storing multiple bools inside a single object may use less storage compared to having distinct bool object for each, if the number of bools is great enough to offset the cost in memory use of the instructions.

Also consider that there are more considerations than space efficiency. Most typically, people are concerned about time efficiency as well. In this regard, compacting bools may more or less efficient depending on the details of the use case.

> is using an integer to store many bool worth the effort?

It can be worth the effort. It can also be counter productive. The difference can be minuscule or significant. Both in terms of time and space efficiency. Most accurate way to find out is to measure it.

It's not necessary to implement this yourself though, since there are solutions in the standard library. `std::vector<bool>` and `std::bitset` both implement compact storage of bools. Using bitfields may also be an option (just remember to not rely on the internal representation).